# Animation and transition at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the first time I ask a question on here so please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

So I'm trying to make a website where I have buttons come flying in at page load and then they will pop out (scaled bigger) when I hover my mouse over. It's been 2 days and I still can't find the answer for how to do it. When I use animation with "forwards" fill mode, the hover doesn't work after the animation. When I use transition, it's not triggered when the page loads. Also each button will have a .06s delay from the other when they fly in.

Thanks

Code: (this is what I got so far. I used java script to generate the buttons and calculate their initial locations.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head data-gwd-animation-mode="quickMode">
 <title id="title">Jack's Desk</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 1.3.2.0521">
 <style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .backgroundImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .mainDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
 </div>
 
 <script style="">
  const OPACITY = 0.8;
  const TRANSITION_TIME = .4;
  const ANIMATION_TIME = 1.1;
  //For the fly in function.
  var index = 0;
  var delay = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
   var theButton = document.createElement("Button");
   document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(theButton);
   theButton.innerText = "Hola number " + i;
   theButton.style.position = "fixed";
   theButton.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + "px";
   theButton.style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight + "px";
   flyIn(theButton, 0.06);
  }
  
  function flyIn(element, additionalDelay) {
   var elementTop = element.offsetTop;
   var elementLeft = element.offsetLeft;
   var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
   var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;
   var angle = Math.atan2(centerY - elementTop, elementLeft - centerX);
   var newTop = - Math.sin(angle) * 390;
   var newLeft = Math.cos(angle) * 390;
   var newStyle = document.createElement("Style");
   newStyle.type = "text/css";
   newStyle.innerHTML = ".label" + index
    + "{opacity:0; -webkit-animation: flyin" + index + " 1.2s forwards; -webkit-animation-delay:" + delay + "s}"
    + "\n.label" + index + ":hover {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); opacity: 1.0;}"
    + "\n@keyframes flyin" + index + "{\nfrom{\n-webkit-transform: translate(" + newLeft + "px, " + newTop + "px) scale(3, 3);\n opacity: 0}" 
    + "\nto{\n-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);\n opacity: " + OPACITY +"\n}"
    ;
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
   element.className = "label" + index;
   
   delay += additionalDelay;
   index++;
  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add what code you do have? We would need to understand what you have your animations/transitions bound to.

Comment: Ok i added the code.

Comment: It maybe messy because I'm more of a programmer than a web designer...

Comment: Have you considered using the jQuery framework? It would be a breeze to accomplish this with jQuery.

Comment: kk give me sec looking at it now

Comment: I guess I'll take a look at that... sigh... another language to start over with.

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda found a dirtily filthiest of the filth workaround (sorry for language) is to set the animation backward. But this way won't allow me to have any delay on the animation because the buttons will show before the animation starts. I guess I have no other choice. Can't be too greedy. :(

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head data-gwd-animation-mode="quickMode">
 <title id="title">Jack's Desk</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 1.3.2.0521">
 <style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  body {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .backgroundImg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .mainDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
 </div>
 
 <script style="">
  const OPACITY = 0.8;
  const TRANSITION_TIME = .4;
  const ANIMATION_TIME = 1.1;
  //For the fly in function.
  var index = 0;
  var delay = 0;

  
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
   var theLabel = document.createElement("Button");
   document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(theLabel);
   theLabel.innerText = "Hola number " + i;
   theLabel.style.position = "fixed";
   theLabel.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + "px";
   theLabel.style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight + "px";
   flyIn(theLabel, 0.06);
  }
  
  function flyIn(element, additionalDelay) {
   var elementTop = element.offsetTop;
   var elementLeft = element.offsetLeft;
   var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
   var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;
   var angle = Math.atan2(centerY - elementTop, elementLeft - centerX);
   var newTop = - Math.sin(angle) * 390;
   var newLeft = Math.cos(angle) * 390;
   var newStyle = document.createElement("Style");
   newStyle.type = "text/css";
   newStyle.innerHTML = ".label" + index
    + "{opacity: " + OPACITY + ";-webkit-transition: all " + TRANSITION_TIME + "s;\n"
    + "-webkit-animation: flyin" + index + " " + ANIMATION_TIME + "2s reverse;}"
    + "\n.label" + index + ":hover {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); opacity: 1.0;}"
    + "\n@keyframes flyin" + index + "{\n100%{\n-webkit-transform: translate(" + newLeft + "px, " + newTop + "px) scale(3, 3);\n opacity: 0}" 
    + "\n0%{\n-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1, 1);\n opacity: " + OPACITY + "!important;}"
    ;
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
   element.className = "label" + index;
   //element.innerText = parseInt(angle * 180 / Math.PI) + ", (" + newLeft + ", " + newTop +")";
   delay += additionalDelay;
   index++;
  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know? but I think this is what your looking for....

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="main"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS (index.js)

```
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", initFly);

function initFly() {
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    for (var i=0; i < 60; i++){
        //
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        main.appendChild(btn);
        btn.innerHTML = "Hola number " + i;
        btn.style.left = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + "px";
        btn.style.top = Math.random() * window.innerHeight + "px";
        //
        var eleTop = btn.offsetTop;
        var eleLeft = btn.offsetLeft;
        var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var angle = Math.atan2(centerY - eleTop, eleLeft - centerX);
        var newTop = Math.sin(angle) * 390;
        var newLeft = - Math.cos(angle) * 390;
        //
        btn.style.transform = "translate("+newLeft+"px,"+newTop+"px)";
        btn.style.opacity = "0.8";  
    }   
}
```

//CSS (index.css)

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}       
button{
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
button:hover{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I think my code was confusing because the newLeft and newTop are supposed to be the locations where they stem from and the eventually translate to (0, 0). Also each one will have a delay after the other.